# Why does a single backslash and a double backslash perform the same escaping in regex?

Tags: php, regex, escaping, backslash

I am trying to match 008/

```
preg_match('/008\\//i', '008/', $matches);
preg_match('/008\//i', '008/', $matches);
```

My question is why do both of the regular expressions work. I would expect the second to work, but why does the double backslash one work?

Comment: The example in your question is trying to match a forward slash, not a backslash.

Comment: Just in case you weren't aware, the `/` as a delimiter is totally arbitrary. When I'm searching for things that contain a slash I will often do something like `preg_match('#008/#', $string, $matches)` so I can avoid the escaping.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `\\` in PHP strings means "escape the backslash". Since `\/` doesn't mean anything it doesn't need to be escaped (even though it's possible), so they evaluate to the same.

In other words, both of these will print the same thing:

```
echo '/008\\//i'; // prints /008\//i
echo '/008\//i';  // prints /008\//i
```

The backslash is [one of the few characters that can get escaped in a single quoted string](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) (aside from the obvious `\'`), which ensures that you can make a string such as `'test\\'` without escaping last quote.

Comment: The forward slash does need to be escaped in a regular expression delimited by `/` though. You're correct in that the end result is the same, and it's this string that's passed to the PCRE code.

Comment: Yeah, I meant that since `'\/'` does not evaluate to anything special, it has the same effect as `'\\/'`. Obviously this particular regex requires the forward slash to be escaped, and both of the examples do that, which is why both work (they're the same).